# Is there any iphone friendly feedback service

Tags: iphone, feedback

I'm looking for an iphone friendly feedback service that can be visited by web browser in my iphone application
I have been checked uservoice and getsatifaction, they are only for desktop browsing, not friendly for iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Satisfaction ***does*** have a great iPhone client framework.  It's called [Satisfaction Remote Component](http://code.google.com/p/satisfactionremotecomponent/).  If you want to see it live, check out the app [Ambiance](http://bit.ly/ambiance)

Comment: Satisfaction Remote Component is now closed source.

Comment: No it's not. There is a closed source app on the store that uses this, but the framework is obviously not closed-source. Please remove your downvote. http://code.google.com/p/satisfactionremotecomponent/source/checkout

Answer (score 4):

Crittercism (http://www.crittercism.com) also has a great product optimized for iphone/ipad and android.  They also do crash reporting which is nice.

Comment: Glad you like it!  Let us know how we can improve :)

Answer (score 1):

Zendesk http://www.zendesk.com/ is more for customer service but works great in iphones (and blackberry etc)

Answer (score 1):

We have a native iOS feedback form that you can link with your iphone app.

For more info: [Adding Feedback To Your iPhone App](http://www.simplefeedback.com/learn/ios.cfm)

The page also has a link to our **free** app in the AppStore that shows the feedback form in action.

Our service also provides a feedback button and feedback form for websites and WordPress blogs.

Answer (score 1):

Neewmare (www.neemware.com) provides app developers the ability to ask very targeted questions inside their app on any screen. You could check it out. (Disclaimer: I work at Neemware.)